# Ubuntu 20.04 crtl key not working with logitech k380

Tags: keyboard, logitech

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and crtl key not working. With my logtech k380 I use the "English US, alt intl" worked very well to Ubuntu 19.10, but crtl not work in 20.04 version.